# can Lightbox2 js library work with divs?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I am about to use [Lightbox2 js library](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) by Lokesh Dhakar on my project.

Before I start editing my code, let me ask you. Is Lightbox2 working with `divs` instead of `links`?

My code dynamically loads image-paths from the db and places them in a div.

Like so

```
var elem = document.createElement("img");
elem.setAttribute("height", "360");
elem.setAttribute("width", "640");

//mpli array came from db
elem.src=mpli[0];

//imagegal is the name of the div
document.getElementById("imagegal").appendChild(elem);
```

Will this work with Lightbox2 of I have to change `divs` to `links`?

Thaks in advance

Comment: not out of the box, but with enough configuration, sure! anything is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, can work with `div` if you put the `div` between the `link`

That way `div` still changes dynamically and the image of the `div` fires up Lightbox when clicked.

So the js is the same as above and the html part is like

```
 <a class="example-image-link"   id="imagegallink" data-lightbox="images-set" >  <div id="imagegal" ></div> </a>
```